# The Description of the Variable of Interest: Binomial VS Negative Binomial Discrete Random Variables

Tags: discrete-distributions

Does it makes sense to say that:

In a binomial distribution we looking for the number of successes in a given number if trials, and in a negative binomial distribution we are looking for the number of trials until a given number of (edit:) **successes** are achieved?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative binomial distribution vs binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176034/negative-binomial-distribution-vs-binomial-distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to say that in a negative binomial distribution we are looking for the number of trials until a given number of *successes* are achieved.

But there are four possible definitions in use:

- number of *failures* until a given number of *successes* are achieved; with support $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and mean $\frac{1-p}{p}r$
- number of *trials* until a given number of *successes* are achieved; with support $\{r,r+1,r+2,\ldots\}$ and mean $\frac{1}{p}r$
- number of *successes* until a given number of *failures* are achieved; with support $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and mean $\frac{p}{1-p}r$
- number of *trials* until a given number of *failures* are achieved; with support $\{r,r+1,r+2,\ldots\}$ and mean $\frac{1}{1-p}r$

Comment: Yes, I meant that and have edited the question accordingly
Thanks for your answer.